# Can't toggle active/inactive states a rows in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I  make a custom view to user easy turn of or turn off a post. Like this image.

[image: screenshot_2017-06-05_16-02-19]

I have an error like:

> POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/apartments/1/active 404 (Not Found).

In `Controller/Admin/ApartmentController.php`:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $variations = Apartment::all();
    $dataType = DataType::where('slug', '=', 'products')->first();
    return view('voyager::apartments.browse', compact('dataType', 'variations'));
}
public function active(Apartment $apartment)
{
    $apartment->active = true;
    $apartment->save();
}
```

In `resources/views/vendor/voyager/apartments/browse.blade.php`:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($variations as $data)
        <tr>
            <?php $checked = ($data->active == 1) ? true : false; ?>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="active" data-id="{{$data->id}}" class="toggleswitch toggleactive" @if($checked) checked @endif>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>

@section('javascript')
    <!-- DataTables -->
    <script>

      $(document).ready(function(){
          $('.toggleswitch').bootstrapToggle();
      });

      function parseActionUrl(action, id) {
          if (action.match(/\/[0-9]+$/)) {
              return action.replace(/([0-9]+$)/, id);
          }
          return action + '/' + id;
      }

      $('.toggleactive').on('change', function() {
          $.post('/admin/apartments/' + $(this).data('id') + '/active', { active: ($(this).is(':checked')) ? 1 : 0, _token : '{{ csrf_token() }}' }, function(){
              toastr.success("Updated success: apartment is actived");
          });
      });


    </script>
@stop
```

... and `routes/web.php`:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Voyager::routes();

    Route::post('apartments/:id/active', 'ApartmentController@active');

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin.user'], 'as' => 'voyager.'], function () {
        Route::resource('apartments', 'Admin\ApartmentController');
    });
});
```

Note:

If I want to when clicking button `On`, show toast message like: `The apartment is enabled`. Else when clicking button `Off` it will show button `The apartment is disabled`.

Have the best way to change this code?

```
$('.toggleactive').on('change', function() {
    $.post('/admin/apartments/' + $(this).data('id') + '/active', { active: ($(this).is(':checked')) ? 1 : 0, _token : '{{ csrf_token() }}' }, function(){
        toastr.success("Updated success: apartment is actived");
    });
});
```

Comment: Run `php artisan route:list` and check if the route is registered and post the results here. In case it isn't then run `php artisan route:clear`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your route to this.

```
Route::post('apartments/{apartment}/active', 'Admin\ApartmentController@active');
```

Also change your controller method to this.

```
public function active(Apartment $apartment)
{
    $apartment->active = request('active');
    $apartment->save();
}
```

**Edit** : Do this to update your toast message based on the request.

```
public function active(Apartment $apartment)
{
    $status = request('active');
    $apartment->active = $status;
    $apartment->save();

    return $status;
}

$('.toggleactive').on('change', function() {
    $.post('/admin/apartments/' + $(this).data('id') + '/active', { active: ($(this).is(':checked')) ? 1 : 0, _token : '{{ csrf_token() }}' }, function(data){
        toastr.success("Updated success: The apartment is " + (data == 1 ? 'enabled' : 'disabled'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you explain at: `{apartment}`. Original I have `Admin\ApartmentController@active`. My typing mistake.

Comment: You are using route model binding. So you need to use the same url segment as the parameter in the controller method for Laravel to resolve your model. Without which you won't receive the `Apartment` model in your method.

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct. It will go to line: `toastr.success`. But I don't know why it doesn't change values of field `active` in my database. Seem I have an error in my code. Can you find that? Thanks.

Comment: Mean: it shows toast message is `Updated success: the apartment is activated`. When I check in the database, it doesn't change values.

Comment: @vanloc Simple error, you're setting the new value to true all the time in your controller. I've updated my answer. You need to use the `active` from the request input as the value.

Comment: Thanks @Sandeesh. I have a question at `Note` in my edited question. Can you help me? Your answer is resolved my problem. :)

Comment: Sure. You can create a new question with relevant info and code.

Comment: It's alway run to `disable`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145900/discussion-between-sandeesh-and-vanloc).